# Allow login to app using IIS only for some users

Tags: iis

I have an app, e.g. SL. It's running on Web Server 2016 using IIS 10.0.
SL has it's own authentication method.
I don't want that any user with SL account be able to login. I want only those accounts that have Windows Authentication. I have ca
My goal: 1. create account for SL for a few users 2. enable Windows Authentication in IIS 3. list those users in IIS
My expectation: only users listed in IIS will be able to login into SL
I prefer not to change web.config directly. In case it's the only option ... how should I modify it?

Thanks

Comment: It is the web application that you must reconfigure.

Comment: Well ... my goal is not to modify application but use IIS to control allow/restrict users to login. Thanks

Comment: I added to web.config element
               <authorization>
       <allow users="abc\user1, abc\user2"/>
       <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
But I've got 404 Error. What I did wrong?

Comment: P.S. Since modifying web.config did not work for me I tried another approach. 
1. I created a user on app SL e.g. user1 
2. I changed Authentication in IIS and set it for 'Windows Authentication" enabled 
3. I went to security Tab of directory where my site is located e.g. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app and added user e.g. win_user01 and granted read, list folders and execute permission. 
Is my expectation of workflow correct: 
user win_user01 is a valid user of our network hence when he'll login into his client 'Windows Authentication" will be in place.

Comment: continue ...
Next .. he opens the browser e.g. Chrome and tries to connect to SL app. He will have to provide user1 creds and be able to login. 
My assumption is: if win_user01 wouldn't be granted access to 'directory 'he would fail to login. Is it correct? 
In other words … only users that are added to directory and granted permission will be able to login into application. Is it correct? 
Thanks